# Help with Linq and dynamic object property in select

Tags: linq, dynamic

The Linq newb alarm is going to sound off rather loudly, and probably the general newb alarm as well, but I have to ask this question because it's driving me nuts.  I have an object MyObject that has a handful of properties, e.g. ID, Number.  There are many more properties than 2, but you get the idea.

I have a generic List of these objects.  From this list I have a requirement to generate a subset of items based on a dynamically set property of MyObject.  So, instead of having

```
Dim lst as New List(Of MyObject)
... code to populate list ...
Dim newlist = (From o In lst Select o.Number Distinct).ToList()
```

I would like to have something that allows me to query a property of the object in the select dynamically, such as

```
Dim lst as New List(Of MyObject)
... code to populate list ...
Dim newlist = (From o In lst Select o.GetType().GetProperty("Number").Name Distinct).ToList()
```

Obviously the above doesn't work as it just returns me a single-item list of the property name.  Is there a relatively simple way to select an object property dynamically in a Linq statement?

Any and all help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
o.GetType().GetProperty("Number").GetValue(o)
```

...in your Select clause.

Comment: BTW your solution (and my edit of your solution) does use reflection and is most likely not the best way to do this.

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks.  I agree that reflection probably isn't the way to go here, using a linq expression would be better.  But I needed to spin this up quick and it looked like wrapping my head around expressions would cost me more time than I have available.